# Warum heißt es eigentlich »recht haben«?

Tags: etymology

Meine Frau macht gerade einen Englisch-Kurs, und um auch mein Englisch ein wenig aufzufrischen, haben wir uns ein wenig auf Englisch miteinander unterhalten. Dabei sagte meine Frau: »you *have* right«. Ich korrigierte sie und sagte, dass es auf Englisch »you *are* right« heißt, und dass das Gegenteil davon »you *are* wrong« ist. Daraufhin fragte sie mich, warum das unterschiedlich ist, aber ich wusste keine kluge Antwort darauf. Darum frage ich nun hier nach:

Warum **hat** man auf Deutsch Recht, während man auf Englisch »richtig **ist.**«

Und warum **hat** man dort Unrecht, oder irrt sich, wo der Engländer »falsch **ist**«?

Die beiden Sprachen haben doch eine gemeinsame Wurzel, und irgendwann, so um die Zeit der Völkerwanderung, muss es dafür einen gemeinsamen Ausdruck gegeben haben. Irgendwie (ohne das ich das genauer begründen kann) erscheint mir die englische Variante logischer, und ich frage mich nun (auch im Namen meiner Frau), ob die deutsche Version (Recht haben) oder die Englische (richtig sein) die ursprünglichere ist, und wie dann die andere entstanden ist.

Comment: Im Bulgarischen geht beides: Прав си! (recht bist-du) und "имаш право!" (du-hast Recht). Falls das von Interesse ist. Die erste Variante ist im Alltag mehr verbreitet, die zweite klingt förmlicher.

Comment: Sonst könnte es ja keine Rechthaberei geben, oder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Englische *right* übersetzt sich hier nicht mit *Recht*, sondern mit *richtig*. Der ganze Ausdruck ist also ein völlig anderer.

Warum sagt man im Deutschen also nicht

> Er ist richtig.

jedoch schon

> Das ist richtig./Es ist richtig, dass …

Offensichtlich ist im Deutschen *richtig oder falsch* etwas, dass ausschließlich ein Sachverhalt sein kann. Das gilt auch für andere Adjektive, die Sachverhalte beschreiben, z.B. *überlegt* oder *unbedacht*.

Comment: Man kann im Deutschen zwar nicht "richtig sein", aber "richtig liegen". Warum das jetzt ausgerechnet *liegen* heißt, tja wer weiß..

Comment: Auch Menschen können falsch sein: *Jaqueline zu Kevin: »Du bist so falsch! Ich will dich nie wieder sehen!«* Aber das bedeutet etwas anderes.

Comment: In meinem Dialekt kann man durchaus sagen "Du meinst, du seist so recht", wenn man sagen möchte, dass der angesprochene sich für moralisch überlegen hält.